# Users can see other users real time data who are connected to socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The code below is to show the real-time progress bar for the downloading batches once the user is connected to the socket and it will update the details in every 5 seconds. Problem is that the when two users are connected to the socket then users can see each other batches progress on their account.

I have tried using a socket.id which is unique but it's not working.

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
      socketUniqueID = socket.id;
      setInterval(
         () => getApiAndEmit(socket),
         5000
      );
      socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
          try {
          socket.emit(socketID, {batchdata : fetchDetail(req.user.id)});
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
          }
};

function fetchDetail(id){
         //CODE TO FETCH THE DETAILS FROM DATABASE
}
```

User can only view the progress of their batches and not of other users who are also logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a private message to a specific socketId, you should use `io.to(SocketIdOfUser).emit('message','my message')`
Also, you can have a look at Socket.Io [emit-cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) to see other examples